# Requests through service-worker are done twice

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api, workbox

I've done a simple service-worker to defer requests that fail for my JS application (following [this example](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync#advanced_usage)) and it works well.
But I still have a problem when requests succeed: the requests are done twice. One time normaly and one time by the service-worker due to the `fetch()` call I guess.

It's a real problem because when the client want to save datas, they are saved twice...

Here is the code :

```js
const queue = new workbox.backgroundSync.Queue('deferredRequestsQueue');
const requestsToDefer = [
  { urlPattern: /\/sf\/observation$/, method: 'POST' }
]
function isRequestAllowedToBeDeferred (request) {
  for (let i = 0; i < requestsToDefer.length; i++) {
    if (request.method && request.method.toLowerCase() === requestsToDefer[i].method.toLowerCase()
      && requestsToDefer[i].urlPattern.test(request.url)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (isRequestAllowedToBeDeferred(event.request)) {
    const requestClone = event.request.clone()
    const promiseChain = fetch(requestClone)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Request added to queue: ${event.request.url}`)
        queue.addRequest(event.request)

        event.respondWith(new Response({ deferred: true, request: requestClone }))
      })

    event.waitUntil(promiseChain)
  }
})
```

How to do it well ?

**EDIT:**

I think I don't have to re-`fetch()` the request (because THIS is the cause of the 2nd request) and wait the response of the initial request that triggered the `fetchEvent` but I have no idea how to do it. The `fetchEvent` seems to have no way to wait (and read) the response.

Am I on the right way ? How to know when the request that triggered the `fetchEvent` has a response ?

Comment: reason for double req - client makes req, fetch listener sees it and makes a second req (as per ur instructions). To prevent this, remove respond with from inside the catch, above waitUntil add event.respondWith(promiseChain) and your done. So your listener watches, takes over, makes req, sends returns adjusted promise to client.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `event.respondWith(...)` asynchronously, inside of `promiseChain`.

You need to call `event.respondWith()` synchronously, during the initial execution of the `fetch` event handler. That's the "signal" to the service worker that it's your `fetch` handler, and not another registered `fetch` handler (or the browser default) that will provide the response to the incoming request.

(While you're calling `event.waitUntil(promiseChain)` synchronously during the initial execution, that doesn't actually do anything with regards to responding to the request—it just ensures that the service worker isn't automatically killed while `promiseChain` is executing.)

Taking a step back, I think you might have better luck accomplishing what you're trying to do if you use the `workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin` along with `workbox.routing.registerRoute()`, following the [example from the docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync#basic_usage):

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /\/sf\/observation$/,
  workbox.strategy.networkOnly({
    plugins: [new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('deferredRequestsQueue')]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

That will tell Workbox to intercept any `POST` requests that match your RegExp, attempt to make those requests using the network, and if it fails, to automatically queue up and retry them via the Background Sync API.

Comment: Ok, but using the backgroundSync plugin, can my app detect that the request has failed BUT is deferred by the service-worker ?

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking Jeff Posnick's answer, you need to call `event.respondWith()` and include the `fetch()` call inside it's `async function()`.

For example:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (isRequestAllowedToBeDeferred(event.request)) {
        event.respondWith(async function(){
            const promiseChain = fetch(event.request.clone())
                .catch(function(err) {
                    return queue.addRequest(event.request);
            });
            event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
            return promiseChain;
        }());
    }
});
```

This will avoid the issue you're having with the second ajax call.